# Prove in this way that the AM-GM is implied

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Given $n$ positive numbers with sum $S$, we are to prove their product must be less than or equal to $\left(\frac{S}{n}\right)^n.$ If the numbers are all equal to their arithmetic mean $\frac{S}{n}$, then clearly equality holds. Otherwise, there must be at least one smaller $A_n = \frac{S}{n}$ and at least one larger.

Then we have:
$a_1 = A_n - h$ and $a_2 = A_n + l$, where $k,l$ are positive. Next choose $a_1'= A_n$ and $a_2'=A_n+l-h$, then consider the product
$a_1'a_2' = (A^2_n+kA_n-hA_n)$, while $a_1a_2 = (A^2_n+kA_n-hA_n)-hk.$

This then implies $(1)\space\space\space a_1'a_2'>a_1a_2$.

Using this I have to prove that it implies the following inequality $$(2)\space\space\space \left(\prod_{i=1}^nx_i\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\le\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}{n}$$ by considering the set of $n$ numbers $y_i$ where $i=1, 2, ..., n$ where
$$y_i = \frac{x_i}{\sum_{k=1}^nx_k}.$$

I had thought of taking some value less then or larger than $y_i$ and incrementing it to produce the first inequality, although I don't know how to proceed with a geometric inequality to show that this direction holds? unless it doesn't.

Comment: One of the proofs here might help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#Proofs_of_the_AM%E2%80%93GM_inequality

Comment: Jensen's inequality gives you the result.

Comment: The "Proof by induction 2" on wikipedia made sense to me...